# Qlikview set date range selection in expression independent of selected values

Tags: qlikview

I wish to select a date range in a chart expression independent of selections in the document in the year and month date fields. I have two expressions that should work, but are not returning any values:

**count({< Discharge_Year=,Discharge_Month=,Discharge = {'>=(Date(Today()-60))and <=Today()'}>}[Row Number])**

or

**count({1< Discharge = {'>=Date(Today()-60)'}>}[Row Number])**

The second expression works when a date is inserted *( '>=01/01/2017'instead of '>=Date(Today()-60)')*: the problem seems to be getting the Today()-60 function to work.

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
The quotes in the >= need to be double quotes, and the Today() function needs date formatting:

Finished expression as follows:

**count({1< Discharge = {">=$(=Date((Today()-60),'DD/MM/YYYY'))"}>}[Row Number])**